# Drawing basic AM signal

Tags: modulation, amplitude

I am confused with how to draw the following AM signal:

S(t)=6cos(12t)+3/2cos(14t)+3/2cos(10t)

Comment: Draw by hand? Using a software? A calculator?

Comment: @Eugene Sh. It doesn't really matter, I just need to draw the graph and note all the values.

Comment: It really does. It is not very intuitive by hand, but a software of the mentioned Wolfram Alpha will do it for you out of the box.

Comment: The formula doesn't look like an AM signal.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. Do I need to have Pro version to see the graph? Because I am not seeing it or am I missing something?

Comment: Probably missing multiplication operators. [Try this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=S(t)%3D6*cos(12*t)%2B3%2F2*cos(14*t)%2B3%2F2*cos(10*t))

Comment: Off topic: this is a question about graphing a superposition of sinusoids without any accurate EE basis for why. AM is \$S(t) = mod(t)*sin(\omega t)\$ for some real modulation function `mod`.

Comment: Just plug an chug, put in values for t every 1/20th apart and graph it out on paper. t is your x value, the s(t) is your y value, do this many many times and connect the dots

Comment: Use Excel.  Set up 4 columns (3 terms + total).  Increment t by 0.02 and do calculations.  I'd go to 1 (for 1 second).

Answer (score 1):

Just plug it directly into the Google search bar, with the operators explicitly written, like this:

6*cos(12*x)+(3/2)*cos(14*x)+(3/2)*cos(10*x)

Google will give you the graph.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look of a preview result using wolfram alpha: [Preview](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=S(x)%3D6cos(12x)%2B3%2F2cos(14x)%2B3%2F2cos(10x))
Here you can also see some procedure steps to solve the equation.